# Android hudson build android-support-v7-appcompat

Tags: android, build, hudson

I have a Android project that is currently built and deployed to a internal website by a `Hudson` build server. Recently we added the `android-support-v7-appcompat` library as a dependency (library project).

My question is, how do I **include** the `android-support-v7-appcompat` resources and library into my build script? Do I copy the actual files into my project with the build script (don't even know if the app will then still recognize the library) or will this automatically happen when the build file (to build the apk) is executed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end the only thing I had to do was generate a build file for the appcompat library. After that the build was successful.